# XML Parsing in Swift 2 (Xcode 7)

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, swift, swift2

I am needing help parsing XML from a URL. I have read on this a lot and cannot figure out how to get this. All the examples I have found are a little ambiguous with the examples and how to grab the info from parsed XML data.

How would I parse this XML

```
<menu>
    <menuitems>
        <item price="$10">Pizza</item>
        <item price="$5">Salad</item>
        <item price="$3">Bread</item>
    </menuitems>
</menu>
```

This is the tutorial I was going off of but I couldn't understand how this tutorial was accessing the data in the arrays and dictionary.

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/xml-parsing-using-nsxmlparse-swift

In Xcode 7 (Swift 2), how would I parse and access this info. I know this is not how it would be accessed but I am looking for something like the code below.

```
print ("\(item[0].data)") // Pizza //
print ("\(item[0].price)") // $10 //
```

Here is the code from the tutorial but I couldn't figure out how to access all the data parsed from the URL. How would I edit this code to fit my structure?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate

    {

    var parser = NSXMLParser()
    var posts = NSMutableArray()
    var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
    var element = NSString()
    var title1 = NSMutableString()
    var date = NSMutableString()

func beginParsing()
{
    posts = []
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string:"http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss"))!)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
}



func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
{
    element = elementName
    if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item")
    {
        elements = NSMutableDictionary()
        elements = [:]
        title1 = NSMutableString()
        title1 = ""
        date = NSMutableString()
        date = ""
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
{
    if element.isEqualToString("title") {
        title1.appendString(string)
    } else if element.isEqualToString("pubDate") {
        date.appendString(string)
    }
}


func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
{
    if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item") {
        if !title1.isEqual(nil) {
            elements.setObject(title1, forKey: "title")
        }
        if !date.isEqual(nil) {
            elements.setObject(date, forKey: "date")
        }
        posts.addObject(elements)

    }

    }

}
```

Comment: You may try [XMLDictionary](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary) which parses XML into NSDictionary.

Comment: when do you call your beginParsing() method ? in the viewDidLoad() ? or it is a delegate method ?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like that parser code was borrowed from something else. If this really is your XML, think it's simpler than that. The only trick in your case is that `price` is not an element, but rather just an `attributeDict` of the `item` element. And I might create my own custom type, `Item` to capture the name and price of an item.

Anyway, you might end up with something like:

```
struct Item {
    let name: String
    let price: String
}

var itemName: String?
var itemPrice: String?
var items: [Item]!

func parserDidStartDocument(parser: NSXMLParser) {
    items = []
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    if elementName == "item" {
        itemPrice = attributeDict["price"]
        itemName = ""
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    itemName?.appendContentsOf(string)
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "item" {
        items.append(Item(name: itemName!, price: itemPrice!))
        itemName = nil
        itemPrice = nil
    }
}
```

When I do that, and print `items`, I get:

> [MyApp.ViewController.Item(name: "Pizza", price: "$10"), 
>   MyApp.ViewController.Item(name: "Salad", price: "$5"), 
>   MyApp.ViewController.Item(name: "Bread", price: "$3")]

Comment: How do I print the name or price a specific item number? For instance, how would you print the name or price of item number 2 in the list.

Comment: `print(items[1].name)` and `print(items[1].price)`